How can I import a function that is in another file inside the script tag of my HTML file?
I am trying to import a function (that is in its own js file) inside the script of my index.html so I can use it for example with a button onclick. I don't want to define the function in the script because it will be too polluted.
This is what I am trying on a very simplified version, for tests:
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="show()">Click Me</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
</body>
<script>
    import { sum }  from './myFunc.js'
    
    const show = () => {
        document.getElementById("result").innerText = sum(2, 4);
    }
</script>
</html>

myFunc.js:
export function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b
} 

Would I need something else that I am missing? I already searched a lot, but nothing helped me yet.
This is the error I get: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects one or two arguments.
And if I click the button it can't find the function show(), as it never made it past the import line.

What browser is this?  The named import statement is relatively recent.

You have to use <script type="module"> in order to use import.

I currently working on safari, and when I use type="module" the error changes to Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

That simply means that the file is not located where you indicated it was.

as stupid as this problem might now seem, I had already checked the location 1000 times, but now I finally managed to find the right one! thank you!!

Step-by-Step Solution

Create the JavaScript module file (myFunc.js):
// myFunc.js
export function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}


Update the HTML file to include the module script:

<body>
    <!-- Use the type="module" attribute to enable ES6 module support -->
    <script type="module">
        import { sum } from './myFunc.js';

        window.show = () => {
            document.getElementById("result").innerText = sum(2, 4);
        };
    </script>
</body>




Explanation

myFunc.js: This file exports the sum function using ES6 module syntax.
index.html:

The <script type="module"> attribute enables the use of ES6 modules.
The import { sum } from './myFunc.js'; line imports the sum function from myFunc.js.



Final Check
Make sure the directory structure looks like this:
project-folder/
├── index.html
└── myFunc.js

